# vCalendar Code ignoring everything after <br> tag in DESCRIPTION field

Tags: coldfusion, vcalendar

I'm passing a description field, after I run a

```
cfset local.description = rereplacenocase(arguments.description,chr(13),'<br>','all')
```

to DESCRIPTION:#local.description#\n

And it is only showing the first line up until that 1st BR. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `replace()` instead. You're not really doing regular expression here...

```
var description = replace(arguments.description, chr(13), '<br>', 'all');
```

Or, use something like [paragraphFormat()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e24.html) or [paragraphFormat2()](http://www.cflib.org/udf/paragraphformat2)